# Intersection of Two Rectangles with paintComponent

Tags: java, swing, intersection

I am writing a program that allows a user to paint rectangles onto a `JLabel`, and show the intersection and union of these rectangles.  I have setup the GUI for the class but am struggling to find a way to integrate the intersection and union methods from the rectangle class.  I know these methods work when used separately from the GUI.

When I try to run the program I keep getting an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` and the drawn rectangles are cleared from the gui.  The intersections of each rectangle should show up in a different color on the `JLabel`.  I tried to debug the program and for some reason when I create two rectangles and store them in my array list many many rectangle objects of the same characteristics are being created.

For the union method, a new rectangle should be create that contains all of the rectangles on the inside.

**RectangleFrame1:**

```
public class RectangleFrame1 extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{


    JPanel buttonPanel;
    JButton saveImage;
    JButton clearImage;
    JCheckBox intersections;
    JCheckBox union;
    RectangleLabel drawingArea;
    boolean intersect = false;
    boolean uni = false;

    public RectangleFrame1()
    {
        super();
        setTitle("Rectangles");
        setSize(600,600);
        setResizable(false);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
        this.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        intersections = new JCheckBox("Draw Intersections");
        buttonPanel.add(intersections);
        intersections.addActionListener(this);
        intersections.setActionCommand("Intersections");

        union = new JCheckBox("Draw Union");
        buttonPanel.add(union);
        union.addActionListener(this);
        union.setActionCommand("Union");

        saveImage = new JButton("Save Image");
        saveImage.setMargin(new Insets(0,0,0,0));
        buttonPanel.add(saveImage);
        saveImage.addActionListener(this);
        saveImage.setActionCommand("Save Image");

        clearImage = new JButton("Clear Image");
        clearImage.setMargin(new Insets(0,0,0,0));
        buttonPanel.add(clearImage);
        clearImage.addActionListener(this);
        clearImage.setActionCommand("Clear Image");

        drawingArea = new RectangleLabel();
        drawingArea.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.blue));
        this.add(drawingArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        drawingArea.addMouseListener((MouseListener) drawingArea);
        drawingArea.addMouseMotionListener((MouseMotionListener) drawingArea);

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
    {
        switch(arg0.getActionCommand())
        {
            case "Intersections":
            if(intersections.isSelected())
            {
                intersect = true;
            }
            else
            {
                intersect = false;
            }
            case "Union":
            if(union.isSelected())
            {
                uni = true;
            }
            else
            {
                uni = false;
            }
            case "Clear Image": drawingArea.clearImage();
            case "Save Image": drawingArea.saveImage();
        }

    }

    class RectangleLabel extends JLabel implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener
    {

        Rectangle rectangle = null;
        int x, y, x2, y2;
        ArrayList<Rectangle> a = new ArrayList();
        int counter;
        public RectangleLabel()
        {
            super();
        }
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0)
        {
            x = arg0.getX();
            y = arg0.getY();

            rectangle = new Rectangle(x, y, 0, 0);
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent arg0)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            x2 = arg0.getX();
            y2 = arg0.getY();

            if(rectangle.getX() > x2)
            {
                rectangle.setWidth(x-x2);
            }
            if(x2 > rectangle.getX())
            {
                rectangle.setWidth(x2-x);
            }
            if(y > y2)
            {
                rectangle.setHeight(y-y2);
            }
            if(y2 > y)
            {
                rectangle.setHeight(y2-y);
            }

            a.add(rectangle);
            counter++;
            repaint();

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0)
        {
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
        {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if(rectangle != null)
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
                {
                    float thickness = 2;
                    ((Graphics2D) g).setStroke(new BasicStroke(thickness));
                    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                    g.drawRect(a.get(i).getX(), a.get(i).getY(), a.get(i).getWidth(), a.get(i).getHeight());
                    g.setColor(Color.gray);
                    g.fillRect(a.get(i).getX(), a.get(i).getY(), a.get(i).getWidth(), a.get(i).getHeight());
                }
            }

            if(intersect == true && counter > 0)
            {
                for(int h = 0; h < counter-1; h++)
                {
                    for(int j = 1; j < counter; j++)
                    {   if(a.get(h).overlaps(a.get(j)))
                        {
                            Rectangle rect = a.get(h).intersect(a.get(j));
                            g.setColor(Color.RED);
                            g.fillRect(rect.getX(), rect.getY(), rect.getWidth(), rect.getHeight());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if(uni == true && counter > 0)
            {
                for(int h = 0; h < counter - 1; h++)
                {
                    for(int j = 1; j < counter; j++)
                    {
                        Rectangle rect = a.get(h).union(a.get(j));
                        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                        g.drawRect(rect.getX(), rect.getY(), rect.getWidth(), rect.getHeight());

                    }
                }
            }
        }


        public void saveImage()
        {
            BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            Graphics2D aaaaa = image.createGraphics();
            aaaaa.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            aaaaa.clearRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
            this.paintAll(aaaaa);
            try
            {
                File output = new File("rectangle.png");
                ImageIO.write(image, "Rectangles", output);
            }
            catch(IOException ie)
            {

            }
        }
        public void clearImage()
        {
            a.clear();
            repaint();
        }

    }

}
```

**Rectangle:**

```
public class Rectangle
{


    private int x,y,width,height;

    public Rectangle(int x,int y,int width,int height)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public Rectangle(Rectangle a)
    {
        this.x = a.x;
        this.y = a.y;
        this.width = a.width;
        this.height = a.height;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return "Start: ("+x+","+y+"), Width: "+width+", Height: "+height+"\n";
    }

    public int getX()
    {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY()
    {
        return y;
    }

    public int getWidth()
    {
        return width;
    }

    public int getHeight()
    {
        return height;
    }

    public void setX(int x)
    {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public void setY(int y)
    {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void setWidth(int width)
    {
        this.width = width;
    }

    public void setHeight(int height)
    {
        this.height = height;
    }

    public int area()
    {
        return width*height;
    }

    public boolean overlaps(Rectangle a)
    {
        if ((x>a.x+a.width) || (a.x>x+width) || (y>a.y+a.height) || (a.y>y+height))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public Rectangle intersect(Rectangle a)
    {
        if (!overlaps(a))
            return null;

        int left,right,top,bottom;

        if (x<a.x)
            left = a.x;
        else
            left = x;

        if (y<a.y)
            bottom = a.y;
        else
            bottom = y;

        if ((x+width)<(a.x+a.width))
            right = x+width;
        else
            right = a.x+a.width;

        if ((y+height)<(a.y+a.height))
            top = y+height;
        else
            top = a.y+a.height;

        return new Rectangle(left,bottom,right-left,top-bottom);
    }

    public Rectangle union(Rectangle a)
    {
        int left,right,top,bottom;

        if (x<a.x)
            left = x;
        else
            left = a.x;

        if (y<a.y)
            bottom = y;
        else
            bottom = a.y;

        if ((x+width)<(a.x+a.width))
            right = a.x+a.width;
        else
            right = x+width;

        if ((y+height)<(a.y+a.height))
            top = a.y+a.height;
        else
            top = y+height;

        return new Rectangle(left,bottom,right-left,top-bottom);
    }
}
```

Comment: What `Rectangle` class are you using?  As `java.awt.Rectangle` doesn't have a `setWidth` method

Comment: It is a rectangle class that I created.

Comment: You might want to provide that as well, otherwise we can't run the code...

Comment: Yeah.  The full stack trace would be good too, and indicate which lines of what you've posted are mentioned in it.  Otherwise, there's a lot to read through to look for possible exceptions.

Comment: Other than the union() method, was there some compelling reason to write your own Rectangle class? I've come up with my own implementations of common objects from time to time, just to get an idea of how things worked, but in practice, I've always gone back to the tried and true.

Comment: Where is the part where you're storing things in the array?

Comment: The only place I add a rectangle to the array is in the mouseDragged method.

Comment: @user2932450 This is a lot of code. Can you please post your stack trace as well as clearly indicate the line that is causing the exception?

Comment: What is the `counter` variable that you're using in `paintComponent`?  It seems to me that you'd get your exception if that were set to the wrong value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of problems...

You're `mouseDragged` event handler is adding the same `Rectangle` to the `a` `ArrayList`, over and over again, increasing the `counter` value along with it.

This is not required.  All you need to do is add the `Rectangle` on the `mousePressed` event.  When `mouseReleased` is called, you could evaluate the `Rectangle` to check if the size is greater than `0x0` and remove it if it's not (ie remove any `Rectangle` whose size is `0x0`)

Don't rely on the `counter` variable, it's too easy for the value to become misaligned with the size of the `a` `List`.  Instead, rely on `a.size` instead.

The `switch` statement in your `ActionListener` is evaluating the matching case, but also all the following cases below it.  This is a feature of `switch`.  If you don't want to evaluate the following cases, you need to add a `break` at the end of each case (or where ever you want to "break" the processing).

For example, when you click `Draw Intersections`, it is also evaluating `Union`, `Clear Image` and `Save Image` cases...

You could try using something like...

```
switch (arg0.getActionCommand()) {
    case "Intersections":
        intersect = intersections.isSelected();
        break;
    case "Union":
        uni = union.isSelected();
        break;
    case "Clear Image":
        drawingArea.clearImage();
        break;
    case "Save Image":
        drawingArea.saveImage();
        break;
}
```

instead...

**Logic Errors in Painting Code...**

There's also a logic area with your `intersect` paint code, where it is comparing a rectangle with itself, which ends up painting the whole rectangle.

Instead of

```
if (a.get(h).overlaps(a.get(j))) {
```

You might consider using

```
if (!a.get(h).equals(a.get(j)) && a.get(h).overlaps(a.get(j))) {
```

This is possibly occurring in you union painting logic as well, but I didn't really check that

**Works fine for me...**

[image]

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class RectangleFrame1 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                RectangleFrame1 frame = new RectangleFrame1();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    JPanel buttonPanel;
    JButton saveImage;
    JButton clearImage;
    JCheckBox intersections;
    JCheckBox union;
    RectangleLabel drawingArea;
    boolean intersect = false;
    boolean uni = false;

    public RectangleFrame1() {
        super();
        setTitle("Rectangles");
        setSize(600, 600);
//        setResizable(false);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
        this.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        intersections = new JCheckBox("Draw Intersections");
        buttonPanel.add(intersections);
        intersections.addActionListener(this);
        intersections.setActionCommand("Intersections");

        union = new JCheckBox("Draw Union");
        buttonPanel.add(union);
        union.addActionListener(this);
        union.setActionCommand("Union");

        saveImage = new JButton("Save Image");
        saveImage.setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
        buttonPanel.add(saveImage);
        saveImage.addActionListener(this);
        saveImage.setActionCommand("Save Image");

        clearImage = new JButton("Clear Image");
        clearImage.setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
        buttonPanel.add(clearImage);
        clearImage.addActionListener(this);
        clearImage.setActionCommand("Clear Image");

        drawingArea = new RectangleLabel();
        drawingArea.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.blue));
        this.add(drawingArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        drawingArea.addMouseListener((MouseListener) drawingArea);
        drawingArea.addMouseMotionListener((MouseMotionListener) drawingArea);

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        switch (arg0.getActionCommand()) {
            case "Intersections":
                intersect = intersections.isSelected();
                break;
            case "Union":
                uni = union.isSelected();
                break;
            case "Clear Image":
                drawingArea.clearImage();
                break;
            case "Save Image":
                drawingArea.saveImage();
                break;
        }
        repaint();
    }

    class RectangleLabel extends JLabel implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {

        Rectangle rectangle = null;
        int x, y, x2, y2;
        ArrayList<Rectangle> a = new ArrayList();

        public RectangleLabel() {
            super();
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
            x = arg0.getX();
            y = arg0.getY();

            rectangle = new Rectangle(x, y, 0, 0);
            a.add(rectangle);
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            x2 = arg0.getX();
            y2 = arg0.getY();

            if (rectangle.getX() > x2) {
                rectangle.setWidth(x - x2);
            }
            if (x2 > rectangle.getX()) {
                rectangle.setWidth(x2 - x);
            }
            if (y > y2) {
                rectangle.setHeight(y - y2);
            }
            if (y2 > y) {
                rectangle.setHeight(y2 - y);
            }

            repaint();

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
            rectangle = null;
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            for (Rectangle rect : a) {
                float thickness = 2;
                ((Graphics2D) g).setStroke(new BasicStroke(thickness));
                g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                g.drawRect(rect.getX(), rect.getY(), rect.getWidth(), rect.getHeight());
                g.setColor(Color.gray);
                g.fillRect(rect.getX(), rect.getY(), rect.getWidth(), rect.getHeight());
            }

            if (intersect) {
                for (int h = 0; h < a.size() - 1; h++) {
                    for (int j = 1; j < a.size(); j++) {
                        if (!a.get(h).equals(a.get(j)) && a.get(h).overlaps(a.get(j))) {
                            Rectangle rect = a.get(h).intersect(a.get(j));
                            g.setColor(Color.RED);
                            g.fillRect(rect.getX(), rect.getY(), rect.getWidth(), rect.getHeight());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (uni) {
                for (int h = 0; h < a.size() - 1; h++) {
                    for (int j = 1; j < a.size(); j++) {
                        if (!a.get(h).equals(a.get(j)) && a.get(h).overlaps(a.get(j))) {
                            Rectangle rect = a.get(h).union(a.get(j));
                            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                            g.drawRect(rect.getX(), rect.getY(), rect.getWidth(), rect.getHeight());

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void saveImage() {
            BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            Graphics2D aaaaa = image.createGraphics();
            aaaaa.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            aaaaa.clearRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
            this.paintAll(aaaaa);
            try {
                File output = new File("rectangle.png");
                ImageIO.write(image, "Rectangles", output);
            } catch (IOException ie) {

            }
        }

        public void clearImage() {
            a.clear();
            repaint();
        }

    }

    public class Rectangle {

        private int x, y, width, height;

        public Rectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;
        }

        public Rectangle(Rectangle a) {
            this.x = a.x;
            this.y = a.y;
            this.width = a.width;
            this.height = a.height;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "Start: (" + x + "," + y + "), Width: " + width + ", Height: " + height + "\n";
        }

        public int getX() {
            return x;
        }

        public int getY() {
            return y;
        }

        public int getWidth() {
            return width;
        }

        public int getHeight() {
            return height;
        }

        public void setX(int x) {
            this.x = x;
        }

        public void setY(int y) {
            this.y = y;
        }

        public void setWidth(int width) {
            this.width = width;
        }

        public void setHeight(int height) {
            this.height = height;
        }

        public int area() {
            return width * height;
        }

        public boolean overlaps(Rectangle a) {
            if ((x > a.x + a.width) || (a.x > x + width) || (y > a.y + a.height) || (a.y > y + height)) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        public Rectangle intersect(Rectangle a) {
            if (!overlaps(a)) {
                return null;
            }

            int left, right, top, bottom;

            if (x < a.x) {
                left = a.x;
            } else {
                left = x;
            }

            if (y < a.y) {
                bottom = a.y;
            } else {
                bottom = y;
            }

            if ((x + width) < (a.x + a.width)) {
                right = x + width;
            } else {
                right = a.x + a.width;
            }

            if ((y + height) < (a.y + a.height)) {
                top = y + height;
            } else {
                top = a.y + a.height;
            }

            return new Rectangle(left, bottom, right - left, top - bottom);
        }

        public Rectangle union(Rectangle a) {
            int left, right, top, bottom;

            if (x < a.x) {
                left = x;
            } else {
                left = a.x;
            }

            if (y < a.y) {
                bottom = y;
            } else {
                bottom = a.y;
            }

            if ((x + width) < (a.x + a.width)) {
                right = a.x + a.width;
            } else {
                right = x + width;
            }

            if ((y + height) < (a.y + a.height)) {
                top = a.y + a.height;
            } else {
                top = y + height;
            }

            return new Rectangle(left, bottom, right - left, top - bottom);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I made all of these changes, but when I activate the intersection check box the intersections do not show.

Comment: That's because you forgot to call `repaint` in the `actionPerformed` method

Comment: This turns everything red. Not just the specific rectangle that is formed by the intersection.

Comment: Yes, see the last section of the answer which discuss a possible logic error in you intersection and union painting code...

Comment: I added that portion before I commented the first time.

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks